# media-ctl commands for Caspa mt9v032 omap-isp: gumstix

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, openembedded, bitbake, gumstix

I am facing problems in getting correct media-ctl commands for Caspa mt9v032 omap-isp.
I followed this tutorial but could not succeed --> [Camera-ISP Driver](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Camera-ISP_Driver)
This tutorial gives more details but also could not succeed:--> [Linux:Camera](http://www.compulab.co.il/workspace/mediawiki/index.php5/CM-T3730%3a_Linux%3a_Camera)

List of my media device information:

```
Opening media device /dev/media0
Enumerating entities
Found 16 entities
Enumerating pads and links
Media controller API version 0.0.0

Media device information
------------------------
driver          omap3isp
model           TI OMAP3 ISP
serial          
bus info        
hw revision     0xf0
driver version  0.0.0

Device topology
- entity 1: OMAP3 ISP CCP2 (2 pads, 2 links)
            type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
            device node name /dev/v4l-subdev0
        pad0: Sink
                [fmt:SGRBG10/4096x4096]
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCP2 input":0 []
        pad1: Source
                [fmt:SGRBG10/4096x4096]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":0 []

- entity 2: OMAP3 ISP CCP2 input (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L
            device node name /dev/video0
        pad0: Source
                -> "OMAP3 ISP CCP2":0 []

- entity 3: OMAP3 ISP CSI2a (2 pads, 2 links)
            type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
            device node name /dev/v4l-subdev1
        pad0: Sink
                [fmt:SGRBG10/4096x4096]
        pad1: Source
                [fmt:SGRBG10/4096x4096]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP CSI2a output":0 []
                -> "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":0 []

- entity 4: OMAP3 ISP CSI2a output (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L
            device node name /dev/video1
        pad0: Sink
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CSI2a":1 []

- entity 5: OMAP3 ISP CCDC (3 pads, 9 links)
            type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
            device node name /dev/v4l-subdev2
        pad0: Sink
                [fmt:SGRBG10/752x480]
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCP2":1 []
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CSI2a":1 []
                <- "mt9v032 3-005c":0 [ENABLED]
        pad1: Source
                [fmt:SGRBG10/752x480
                 crop.bounds:(0,0)/752x480
                 crop:(0,0)/752x480]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP CCDC output":0 []
                -> "OMAP3 ISP resizer":0 []
        pad2: Source
                [fmt:SGRBG10/640x479]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP preview":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP AEWB":0 [ENABLED,IMMUTABLE]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP AF":0 [ENABLED,IMMUTABLE]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP histogram":0 [ENABLED,IMMUTABLE]

- entity 6: OMAP3 ISP CCDC output (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L
            device node name /dev/video2
        pad0: Sink
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":1 []

- entity 7: OMAP3 ISP preview (2 pads, 4 links)
            type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
            device node name /dev/v4l-subdev3
        pad0: Sink
                [fmt:SGRBG10/640x479
                 crop.bounds:(10,4)/622x471
                 crop:(10,4)/622x471]
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":2 [ENABLED]
                <- "OMAP3 ISP preview input":0 []
        pad1: Source
                [fmt:YUYV/622x471]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP preview output":0 []
                -> "OMAP3 ISP resizer":0 [ENABLED]

- entity 8: OMAP3 ISP preview input (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L
            device node name /dev/video3
        pad0: Source
                -> "OMAP3 ISP preview":0 []

- entity 9: OMAP3 ISP preview output (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L
            device node name /dev/video4
        pad0: Sink
                <- "OMAP3 ISP preview":1 []

- entity 10: OMAP3 ISP resizer (2 pads, 4 links)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev4
        pad0: Sink
                [fmt:YUYV/622x471
                 crop.bounds:(0,0)/621x471
                 crop:(0,0)/621x471]
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":1 []
                <- "OMAP3 ISP preview":1 [ENABLED]
                <- "OMAP3 ISP resizer input":0 []
        pad1: Source
                [fmt:YUYV/640x480]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP resizer output":0 [ENABLED]

- entity 11: OMAP3 ISP resizer input (1 pad, 1 link)
             type Node subtype V4L
             device node name /dev/video5
        pad0: Source
                -> "OMAP3 ISP resizer":0 []

**- entity 12: OMAP3 ISP resizer output (1 pad, 1 link)
             type Node subtype V4L
             device node name /dev/video6
        pad0: Sink
                <- "OMAP3 ISP resizer":1 [ENABLED]

- entity 13: OMAP3 ISP AEWB (1 pad, 1 link)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev5
        pad0: Sink
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":2 [ENABLED,IMMUTABLE]

- entity 14: OMAP3 ISP AF (1 pad, 1 link)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev6
        pad0: Sink
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":2 [ENABLED,IMMUTABLE]

- entity 15: OMAP3 ISP histogram (1 pad, 1 link)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev7
        pad0: Sink
                <- "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":2 [ENABLED,IMMUTABLE]

- entity 16: mt9v032 3-005c (1 pad, 1 link)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev8
        pad0: Source
                [fmt:SGRBG10/752x480
                 crop:(1,5)/752x480]
                -> "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":0 [ENABLED]**
```

I guess video6 starts from entity 12. I tried to give the following media-ctl commnds, but it is not working.

```
$ media-ctl -r -l '"mt9v032 3-005c":0->"OMAP3 ISP CCDC":0[1], "OMAP3
ISP CCDC":2->"OMAP3 ISP preview":0[1], "OMAP3 ISP preview":1->"OMAP3
ISP resizer":0[1], "OMAP3 ISP resizer":1->"OMAP3 ISP resizer
output":0[1]'

$ media-ctl -V '"mt9v032 3-005c":0[SGRBG10 752x480], "OMAP3 ISP
CCDC":2[SGRBG10 752x480], "OMAP3 ISP preview":1[UYVY 752x480], "OMAP3
ISP resizer":1[UYVY 752x480]'
```

After giving these commands, when I try to run any Gstreamer pipeline, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to enumerate possible video formats device '/dev/video6' can work with
```

...

```
Failed to get number 0 in pixelformat enumeration for /dev/video6. (25 - Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

Can anyone show me how to set proper media-ctl commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
media-ctl -v -r -l '"mt9v032 3-005c":0->"OMAP3 ISP CCDC":0[1], "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":2->"OMAP3 ISP preview":0[1], "OMAP3 ISP preview":1->"OMAP3 ISP resizer":0[1], "OMAP3 ISP resizer":1->"OMAP3 ISP resizer output":0[1]' 

media-ctl -v -V '"mt9v032 3-005c":0[SGRBG10 640x480], "OMAP3 ISP CCDC":2[SGRBG10 640x480], "OMAP3 ISP preview":1[UYVY 640x480], "OMAP3 ISP resizer":1[UYVY 640x480]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the debugging infos from gstreamer
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+11%3A+Debugging+tools

I had to patch gstreamer and omap isp for the streaming to work properly
But using the test video source one can test pipeline already.

I use Overo with DM3730, caspa and tobi/palo35/chestnut